# How can I append text and image to an existing image in dot.net but in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm trying to append text and images to an existing image in .NET.

Since my code is large, I have uploaded it [here](https://github.com/sharifrezvani/Watermarker/blob/main/ImageHandler.cs).

It works, but the problem is that it attaches text to the image in reverse.

This problem only happens on Linux and RTL languages.

However, on Windows, or for LTR languages it works just fine.

How can I fix this problem? Is there any other library that I can use under Linux that supports this requirement?

I need to be able to put logos and texts on a given image.

I have uploaded my current code [here](https://github.com/sharifrezvani/Watermarker/blob/main/ImageHandler.cs)